# Hide Scrollbar from Facebook iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, scrollbar

The question has been asked prior but no clear response was obtained

I an using Facebook's plugin which lets one embed and promote any public Facebook Page on a website

I am trying to hide not remove the scroll bar from the side 
I still want scroll functionality but I do not want the scrollbar to be visible 
What is the best method to achieve this functionality

https://jsfiddle.net/wesuf2tq/1/

```
 <md-card style="width:auto">
    <md-card-header style="background-color: dodgerblue; font-size:15px;font-weight:600; color: white; ">
       <i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:40px; margin:0 auto"></i>
    </md-card-header>
    <div class="facebookContainer" >
       <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FKobe%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId"
               height="800" style="width:100%;border:none;overflow:hidden;"
               scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"
               allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
    </div>
 </md-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no way to achieve this at all - the plugin loads its content into the iframe from a different origin, so the Same Origin Policy prevents you from accessing anything inside it via JavaScript, or to inject any custom styling.

You are limited to the configuration options Facebook offers here - and hiding the scrollbar is not one of them.